# Retrieve labels from p-chart on click

Tags: angular, charts, primeng

I am using the Primeng chart components specifically the pie-chart.
I am able to render the pie chart properly.

However, I am now looking to call a method on the click on any of the labels defined on the pie-chart.
Based on the label selected on the pie-chart, I need to filter data in table in another angular component.

Can anyone guide me how could I retrieve the label of the selected pie-chart?

pie-chart.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<h4> Tasks by Application </h4>
<p-chart type="pie" [data]="p_data" (onDataSelect)="filterByApp($event)"></p-chart>
```

pie-chart.component.ts

```
filterByApp(event) {
  console.log('You pressed chart by application on label: ' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with different permutations and combinations I was able to get the solution.

The method to obtain the selected label is -

```
this.p_data.labels[event.element._index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    module2ChartSelectData(e: any){
      console.log(this.module2Charts.labels[e.element.index]);
    }
```

```html
<p-chart *ngIf="module2Type == 'bar'" type="bar" [data]="module2Charts" [options]="barOptions2" width="250" height="234"></p-chart>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.